# Cutting a 1500 W heating coil into two halves and using one half for a project

Tags: voltage, power, heat, coil, power-engineering

I have a heating coil (Nichrome coil) of 1500 W working at 230 V. I need to cut it into two halves and use one half for my requirement at 230 V without burning my coil.

I know that if I use half the coil with 230 V directly it will draw more current and will work at 3000 W.

What I need is for it to work at 230 V at half of it original length at around 1500 W. What is the solution for this?

Comment: How about getting a properly sized heating element without cutting it? Cutting and splicing the resistive wire has its own quirks. All answers assume that you have a simple resistive wire as a heating element, this may or may not be the case, you need to specify.

Comment: Making the coil half the length but trying to extract the same power will require that the half coil that remains to output twice its rated power, which may well burn it out.

Answer (score 3):

A crude solution would be to put a diode in series, so it would only pass current in every other half-cycle.  That’s not a good thing to do though, as the power factor will be awful and it may affect other equipment nearby.  A 230 to 115V autotransformer would be a better option.

Comment: The reduced voltage would need to be nearly 163 V, not 115 V.

Comment: Is it possible to use a resistor along with the heating coil so as to make the total resistance equal to the heating coil when it was in its full length. Will it cause the resistor to produce more heat than the coil(half length)?

Comment: @vu2nan: can you elaborate? I think you may have confused something. For the same power per unit length the voltage should be directly proportional to the element length.

Comment: @Transistor - Hi, The heater is rated 230 V 1500 W.  Half-heater rating would be 115 V 750 W. To double the half-heater wattage, the applied voltage should be √(115² * 2) = 162.64 V.

Comment: @vu2nan, you are correct. I missed that the operator was trying to get the same power out of half the element. It doesn't sound a though this would end well.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that if I use the half coil to 230 V directly it will draw more current and will work at 3000 W.

Correct but you're now burning twice the energy in half the length so the energy per unit length of element has gone up by a factor of four.

> What I need is to work at 230 V half of it original length at around 1500 W itself.

The solution might be a phase-controlled dimmer.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phase-angle triac control is a means of controlling AC power. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).*

To maintain power density as originally designed you would use a true RMS AC voltmeter and adjust the trigger angle until you had 115 V across the element.

---

Tip: 'V' for volt. 'W' for watt, etc.

See my linked article for more.

Comment: Is it possible to use a resistor along with the heating coil so as to make the total resistance equal to the heating coil when it was in its full length. Will it cause the resistor to produce more heat than the coil(half length)?

Comment: When you cut the element in half you already have a series resistor to add in series. Effectively you've got half the original heater in your heating application and half outside.  They will both dissipate the same power. The problem is that the outside one will not have a heat sink (such as the fluid or solid the other half is in) so it may overheat. You certainly have a problem if you try to get 3000 W out of half the element.